# ElasticBeanStalk Environment running Slow - Degraded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I started started running an app on Elasticbeanstalk. After a few hours the website starts to run tremendously slow (ie. multiple seconds just to load a simple page.) In the health it states the CPU is running at 100% even when there is literally no traffic. In the eb console it shows this

[image]

[image]

I am fairly new to eb so not entirely sure how to troubleshoot this. I am running a t2.micro instance. Is this possibly the issue?

Comment: Your app uses 99% cpu. Maybe its buggy and goes into some crazy loop?

Comment: Ya maybe. I'll have to figure out if there is a bug in there somewhere. I have run it on a local server for days and got no issues but maybe in the translation to eb there was an issue.